# Set default program based on file duration

Tags: windows-10, audio

Is there a way to set the default programs based on media duration in Windows 10?
For example, open audio files (.wav, .mp3, ...) less than 20 seconds with Winamp and others with MusicBee.

Comment: In short... no.

Answer (score 0):

While you cant change the default application association based on duration of media files there are several possibilities that you might consider exploring:

1. sort your media by using the 'duration' column in explorer and then manually creating playlists with each media player respective to duration.
2. write a script that would sort through your media and make a playlist based on duration. [This article](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/powershell-get-mp3mp4-files-metadata-and-how-to-use-it-to-make-you-life-easy/) shows a few creative ways that meta data (including duration), can be used in scripts.

Both these methods however would require that you update the playlists when new media is added to the libraries. While this is not exactly what you asked for, I believe this is a great question that could yield many creative results. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is only on way to archive it: Change the format `.mp3` to `.mp3l` `.mp3s` for MP3 long and MP3 short.
Than you can assign each file extension its own software, which would solve your issue.

This can be archived with batch and ffprobe.exe. You can find ffprobe.exe included in ffmpeg codec tools.

Just read out each duration and than change the file ending `.mp3` to individual endings. Than assign individual programs to do so.

I will not give a ready code, but I recently wrote a powerful music conversion tool, so I can give you helpful snippets. Please only use them for private though.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cls


                REM ### Configuration ###

set LogEnabled=1&&      REM    1 = Save reports to log.txt  | 0 = Save no logfile
set ResetLog=1&&        REM    1 = Delete old log       | 0 = Continue in old log




                REM ### Initialisation ###


IF !LogEnabled! == 1 (
    ECHO Logging is enabled
) ELSE (
    ECHO Logging is disabled
)


set @InPath=%~dp0input\&&   REM defining input path
set @OutPath=%~dp0output\&& REM defining input path
set @RootPath=%~dp0&&       REM defining batch path
set @InDrive=%~d0\&&        REM defing current drive letter

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%@InPath%\"

if !ResetLog! == 1 (
    del /F /Q "!@RootPath!log.txt"
)


set timestamp=!DATE:/=-!_!TIME::=-!
set timestamp=!timestamp: =!
set timestamp=!timestamp:-=:!
set timestamp=!timestamp:_= - !
IF !LogEnabled! == 1 (
    ECHO # !timestamp! # Starting conversion >>"%RootPath%..\log.txt"
)



                REM ### Read all listed audio files ###
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%Z in ("!@RootPath!aformats.cfg") do (
(
    for /r %%a in (*.%%Z) do (

set @InPath=%~dp0input\&&   REM defining input path
set @OutPath=%~dp0output\&& REM defining input path
set @RootPath=%~dp0&&       REM defining batch path
set @InDrive=%~d0\&&        REM defing current drive letter

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


set FileLoc=%%~dpa%%~nxa

set FileLocRel=%%~dpa%%~nxa
set FileLocRel=!FileLocRel:%@InPath%=!

set OutLocRel=%%~dpa%%~nxa
set OutLocRel=!OutLocRel:%@InPath%=!
set OutLoc=%@RootPath%output\!OutLocRel!


for %%F in ("!FileLoc!") do (
    set FileName=%%~nxF
    set ShortFileName=%%~nF
    ECHO FILENAAAAAME: !ShortFileName!
    call set OutDir=%%OutLoc:!FileName!=%%
    call set OutLoc=%%OutLoc:!FileName!=%%!!ShortFileName!.mp3
)

ECHO Now processing: !FileLocRel!...
set timestamp=!DATE:/=-!_!TIME::=-!
set timestamp=!timestamp: =!
set timestamp=!timestamp:-=:!
set timestamp=!timestamp:_= - !
IF !LogEnabled! == 1 (
    ECHO # !timestamp! # Now processing: !FileLocRel!... >>"%RootPath%..\log.txt"
)



"%@RootPath%bin\ffprobe.exe" -i "!FileLoc!" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >>..\length.temp&&     REM reading length value into a temp file for later access

"%@RootPath%bin\ffprobe.exe" -i "!FileLoc!" -show_entries format=size -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >>..\size.temp&&       REM reading size value into a temp file for later access
            REM these are required to calculate the output bitrate


set length=0&&      REM Resetting length (in case of corrupted file)
set size=0&&        REM Resetting size (in case of corrupted file)

for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ('type "!@RootPath!length.temp"') do (
set length=%%T
)&&         REM Reading length from file as a value

for /F "tokens=*" %%S in ('type "!@RootPath!size.temp"') do (
set size=%%S
)&&         REM Reading size from file as a value


            REM Check, if detected file has size and duration - if not, is invalid

set SeemsInvalid=0
IF !size! GTR 0 (
    Echo donothing>>nul
) ELSE (
    set SeemsInvalid=1
)

IF !length! GTR 0 (
    Echo donothing>>nul
) ELSE (
    set SeemsInvalid=1
)

set timestamp=!DATE:/=-!_!TIME::=-!
set timestamp=!timestamp: =!
set timestamp=!timestamp:-=:!
set timestamp=!timestamp:_= - !
IF !SeemsInvalid! EQU 1 (
    Echo !FileLocRel! seems to be corrupted or invalid. Ignoring file...
    IF !LogEnabled! == 1 (
        Echo # !timestamp! # Error: !FileLocRel! seems to be corrupted or invalid. Ignoring file... >>"%RootPath%..\log.txt"
    )
)


        REM     Check if Output subdirectories exist. If not, create them.

IF EXIST "!OutDir!" (
    ECHO DONOTHING>>nul
) ELSE (
    MKDIR "!OutDir!"
)






IF !SeemsInvalid! == 0 (
    SET /A InBitrate=size*6
    SET /A InBitrate=InBitrate/length

    IF InBitrate GTR 320000 (
        set InBitrate=320000
    )


    set BitRate=128000
    set timestamp=!DATE:/=-!_!TIME::=-!
    set timestamp=!timestamp: =!
    set timestamp=!timestamp:-=:!
    set timestamp=!timestamp:_= - !
    ECHO # !timestamp! # "%@RootPath%bin\ffmpeg.exe" -n -i "!FileLoc!" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a !InBitrate! -o "!OutLoc!" >>"%RootPath%..\log.txt"
    "%@RootPath%bin\ffmpeg.exe" -n -i "!FileLoc!" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a !InBitrate! "!OutLoc!"
)




del /F /Q "!@RootPath!length.temp"&&        REM Cleaning up temp files for next loop
del /F /Q "!@RootPath!size.temp"&&      REM Cleaning up temp files for next loop
)
)
)
```

Explenation:
This batch file was in the same folder as the following files:

- batchfile.bat
- aformats.cfg (a list of input formats e.g.: MP3  M4A  WMA and so on. One format/file ending per line)
- input (input any folder. This will reconstruct the same folder hirarchy!!! So no worries for complex folder tree structures, they remain unchanged)
  output (here all files get encoded too with the same folder structure as before [only MP3])
- bin\ffmpeg.exe (all DLLs packed into exe in this case)
- bin\ffprobe.exe (all DLLs packed into exe in this case)

This code just re-encodes every format listed in aformats.cfg to MP3 with a slightly higher bitrate. The target bitrate gets aproximated by duration and size, both get read from ffprobe.exe

Just look for this part of the code, how I managed to archive this. This can easily be rewritten, not to reencode the files, just to rename the filename.mp3 to filename.mp3l, if it is a long MP3 for example. You can change the formats or whatever. Higly customizable. Just above the lines, which read the size and length is also some code I use, to modify the paths and filenames, which needs to be changed to your desired usecase.

Remember: This code is free to use for private use only. Please respect, that this required a ton of work (many hours of testing, debugging etc.)

Please also let me know, if you understood, what to do to archive your goal.

Remember: the filename.mp3l will not be readable by music players. So if this is required, you should create a copy of this batch file and change it to work the other way around. Add the lines to aformats.cfg:

- MP3L
- MP3S
- Whatever file extension you used.

And the output should be MP3 for my example here. Only your fantasy limits, what you could rewrite it to do. It also logs some basic things to log.txt with time stamp. Remember: Change the code, to not encode the files, just to rename them. I recommend to use MP3L for VLC for example, since it does not care much about the file extension - other players likely would. You could also use .mkv or similar as extension, which supports MP3 and can be read by many standard programs.

This tool is VERY powerful! You could basically move a whole HDD into \input folder and press the batch file. It will loop through everything! If special characters are required, you need to change the letter encoding of the .bat file. Than it will support signs like Ä Ö Ü and so on. I just did not care for some trashy MP3s.

I would love a thanks.